# rtmpdump producing corrupt MP3 files

Tags: mp3, audio-streaming, rtmp

Out of all the music players I have, only Windows Media Player is able to play my .mp3 file produced from an rtmpdump of a audio stream. All my other media players, even VLC player are unable to correctly play the file. Whether it be they say the file is corrupt, or that they play nothing, they all have a problem but WMP. Even uploading to a service such as Mixcloud will say that my MP3 is not correct.

Here is the command I'm using to obtain an mp3 from a audio stream:

```
#!/bin/sh
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://w1-ovh.evanovradio.com/live" --playpath "CIDCFM" -o /home/jhvisser/Music/driveAt5_$(date +%y%m%d).mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rtmpdump` don't produce MP3 files, it produces FLV files (even if it only contains audio). Some players ignore the file extension and detect the format automatically from the file content, thats why it may work in some players but not in others.

Use `ffmpeg` to extract the audio from this file:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv -vn -acodec copy file.mp3
```